# Does swapping the value within the list exchange reference in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, list, swap

I am wondering if exchanging the values within the list items like below just exchange the value or the reference address.

> a = [1, 2]

```
a[0], a[1] = a[1], a[0]

print(a) # [2, 1]
```

Under the hood of the mechanism of Python3, I am wondering which one from below is equivalent to the code above.

Case1: Inserting the value itself

```
a[0], a[1] = 2, 1
```

Case2: swap the reference of that item(so only the references are changed but not the value itself)

```
a[0], a[1] = (address of 2nd element), (address of 1st element)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, memory is assigned for **values** not the variables. You can verify this via below.

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 1
>>> hex(id(a))
'0x102ecdbf0'
>>> hex(id(b))
'0x102ecdbf0'
>>> x = [0,1]
>>> hex(id(x[0]))
'0x102ecdbd0'
>>> hex(id(x[1]))
'0x102ecdbf0'
>>> x[0],x[1] = x[1],x[0]
>>> hex(id(x[0]))
'0x102ecdbf0'
>>> hex(id(x[1]))
'0x102ecdbd0'
```

Here, a,b,x[1] shares the same address as the value is same.

So all the variables pointing to the same value will have the same memory address. Upon changing a variable value, **the variable is mapped to address of the new value** appropriately.

For your case, it can be treated as *swap of reference*.

Comment: But I think that is just the `id` of the number which is `1` itself. `hex(id(1))` and `hex(id(a[0]))` returns the same value.

Comment: Updated the answer.